# trying to install .net framework on mac os

Tags: macos, .net-framework

i'm using a program called "wine" that allows me to run .exe files on my macbook pro (running snow leopard) but to run this specific program I need to have Microsoft .NET framework installed, but when I try to install it gets almost all the way through to process and gives me this error message:

this was for .net framework 3.5
EventType : visualstudio8setup
P1 : 14001
P2 : 3.5.21022.08_orcas_x86_net
P3 : pr
P4 : inst
P5 : f
P6 : gencomp7051025_{168d82f8-ac6b-4b55-804f-2ae51
P7 : baseret_failure
P8 : 0
P9 : 1603
P10 : -

so just to see if that install stuck at all, I tried the 3.5 service pack 1 and got this message:
EventType : visualstudio8setup
P1 : 35101
P2 : 3.5.30729.01_orcas_x86_net
P3 : gen
P4 : inst
P5 : f
P6 : dlmgr_verificationerror
P7 : 5008
P8 : 5008
P9 : type_badcertificate
P10 : -

any help or alternative solutions to make this work would be great. One of my friends in a similar situation said he installed it using VMWare, but he got that software from his work and I would love to not have to buy anything. Thanks!

Comment: this isn't a programming question and would be better asked on [su], where "power users" hang out...

Comment: @Evan: If the software is pure .NET, Mono may be able to run it: http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX